# Structuring html document

Tags: html

I have taken over some software which produces a html document with no structure.
The HTML in it self is good enough. Well enclosed and nested and what not but it is almost impossible to read with the human eye as the linebreaks are how the tekst editor, used to view the document, pleases.

So, my question is as follows.

Does any of you know a online parser or program that allows the showing of a messy, more or less minified html document, to show a human readable document? Preferablly also indenting he various tags to show nested levels of the tags

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would have found it to be the first link on a google search.

Answer (score 2):

Try this maybe (just picked the first link for a 'html online tidy' google search). http://infohound.net/tidy/

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://infohound.net/tidy/).

It is online and it is free.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any HTML editor will have this capability. For instance: HTMLKit

Answer (score 0):

The JS Beautifier also works with HTML: http://jsbeautifier.org/

There are other, similar tools available online if you search.